# Apache spark: reading from csv files and creating RDDes

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have two files: airports.csv and flights.csv.
Airports have columns: IATA_CODE    AIRPORT CITY    STATE   COUNTRY LATITUDE    LONGITUDE.
Flights have columns: YEAR  MONTH   DAY DAY_OF_WEEK AIRLINE FLIGHT_NUMBER   TAIL_NUMBER ORIGIN_AIRPORT  DESTINATION_AIRPORT SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE DEPARTURE_TIME  DEPARTURE_DELAY TAXI_OUT    WHEELS_OFF  SCHEDULED_TIME  ELAPSED_TIME    AIR_TIME    DISTANCE    WHEELS_ON   TAXI_IN SCHEDULED_ARRIVAL   ARRIVAL_TIME    ARRIVAL_DELAY   DIVERTED    CANCELLED   CANCELLATION_REASON AIR_SYSTEM_DELAY    SECURITY_DELAY  AIRLINE_DELAY   LATE_AIRCRAFT_DELAY WEATHER_DELAY.

I read the files in:

```
val airports = sc.textFile("./archive/airports_b.csv")
val flights = sc.textFile("./archive/flights_b.csv")
```

Created RDDes, followed instructions in different websites:

```
val airportRDD: RDD[(VertexId, (String))] = airports.map { line => 
  val row = line split ','
  (row(1).toLong, (row(2))) //1 IATA code, 2 - Airport name
}

val flightsRDD: RDD[Edge[String]] = flights.map {line => 
val row = line split ','
Edge(row(7).toLong, row(8).toLong, row(17)) // 7 Original Airport, 8 Destination Airport, 17 Distance
}

val graph = Graph(airportRDD, flightsRDD)
```

My next step is to just take first three samples:

```
println("Airports: " + airportRDD.take(3))
println("Flights: "+ flightsRDD.take(3))
```

But I am getting following error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 25.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 25.0 (TID 58) (host.docker.internal executor driver): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ABE"
```

Could someone advise what's wrong in the code?

Comment: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ABE"` - you're trying to convert a string ABE to a long, which failed

Comment: Do I need then do convert all IATA CODEs to Numeric? Is there even available LabelEncover or StringIndexer as in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Indexing in scala is zero based - first column is `row(0)` instead of `row(1)` and so on.
Besides it is easier to use `spark.read.option("headers",true).csv(hdfs_path)` lo load csv file i/o parsing it manually. If headers are not present, then you don't need `option("headers",true)`.